# Is it safe to pass std::function<bool(std::string)> &&callback (i.e. as a rvalue move) and what is the effect?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Given the following working code (main.cpp):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct worker
{
   std::function<bool(std::string)> m_callback;
   void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback) // <--- this line
   {
      m_callback = std::bind(callback, std::placeholders::_1);
      callback("hello world!\n");
   }
};


// pretty boring class - a cut down of my actual class
struct helper
{
   worker the_worker;
   bool work_callback(std::string str)
   {
      std::cout << str << std::endl;
      return false;
   }
};

int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   the_helper.the_worker.do_work( [&](std::string data){ return the_helper.work_callback(data); });
}
```

Compiled with: `-std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O2 main.cpp`

I have comment the line in question (`<-- this line` - around line 7), where I think it would be more efficient to use: `void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)>&& callback)` i.e. using the `&&` move semantic.

I have never really used this, mostly because I still don't quite understand it.

My understanding is this:

`void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback)` - will take a copy of the lambda that I pass in (which is an rvalue I think).

`void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback)` - will move the lambda that I pass in because it is an rvalue.

My crude idea of an rvalue is any temporary variable.

Questions:

1. What I am not 100% clear about is, is what I wrote correct? and therefore is it safe to use `&&`. Both seem to work.
2. Does this `&&` method also work if instead of passing a lambda like this:

`the_helper.the_worker.do_work( [&](std::string data){ return the_helper.work_callback(data); });`

we pass in std::bind(...):

`the_worker.do_work(std::bind(&helper::work_callback, the_helper, std::placeholders::_1));`

Comment: You don't need the `std::bind` call, just assignment `m_callback = callback;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know - you'll have to just forgive this crappy example! (its hard to make a simple example just to show a point without makeing crap code)... but I do want to pass and store the callback in this way (i.e. with lambda or bind). I just really want to focus on the pass type (i.e. by value or by `&&`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parameter is defined as an rvalue-reference, you must pass a temporary or cast an lvalue to an rvalue, like with `std::move()`.

And the semantics of rvalue-references are that the caller should expect the passed argument to be plundered, rendering it valid but arbitrary, meaning mostly useless.

But the function receiving an rvalue-reference, despite having *license to plunder*, does not have any *obligation to plunder*. And if it doesn't explicitly do so, for example by passing that license on, then it doesn't come to pass, and nothing special happens.

Your code is such a case.

While I would ban `std::bind` from my vocabulary, using it or not doesn't actually make any significant difference.

Comment: I am reading and re-reading the words you wrote, but I think I am too simple to get it!. I think I understand what you are saying about the `std::move()` - this means that if its an lvalue (like an object or such?) then you move it. Could you explain that last part like I am a child, as in: what happens in the two cases in my code (i.e. is it actually moved?). Thanks :)

Comment: No, it isn't moved, because even though you use rvalue-references at *some* points, you don't use them anywhere they would cause a change in behaviour, aka cause the object to be moved from.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your issue with `std::bind`? are you referring to both/all usages of it, or just the usage with passing functions (i.e. the second one)?

Comment: @code_fodder: My issue with `std::bind` is that a lambda is both cleaner, and sometimes potentially more efficient. Admittedly, `std::bind` has the Advantage of producing the same type for the same arguments repeatedly, instead of being unique to each case.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just checking there was not somthing explcitly bad about it - your just saying its effectivly obsoleted by lambdas :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case regardless of whether you pass by value or by rval ref a temporary std::function will have to be created, that's because a lambda is not really a std::function. In any case, you should move the std::function before assigning, to avoid making an unnecessary copy.
I'd recommend passing by value in this case, as this is a bit more flexible, and if you are passing lambdas, then it does not cause any harm, as the std::function will usually be constructed in place (so the temporary will not be moved into the function; this move can, and usually will, be elided).

Comment: Ok, so, in general, passing a lambda by copy is just the easier/flexible method and we don't by using rvalref?

Comment: You are not passing a lamda here really, you are using it to create a temporary std::function object, which is then passed into the function. so there are a couple of things that can happen here, e.g. the temporary will be created and then moved into the function or the std::function will be created in place. In practice the second one is much more likely, which is the same thing that would happen if you passed by rval ref.